# Table of Contents entry width

Tags: table-of-contents, formatting

I am trying to break entries before the text runs into the page number column, right now I get this:

[image]

Right now I have the following from a `.cls` file:

```
\renewenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
 {\chapter*{\bibname
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\bibname}
    \@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname}{\MakeUppercase\bibname}}%
\begin{singlespace} %
  \list{\@biblabel{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
       {\settowidth\labelwidth{\@biblabel{#1}}%
        \leftmargin\labelwidth
        \advance\leftmargin\labelsep
        \@openbib@code
        \usecounter{enumiv}%
        \let\p@enumiv\@empty
        \renewcommand\theenumiv{\@arabic\c@enumiv}}%
  \sloppy
  \clubpenalty4000
  \@clubpenalty \clubpenalty
  \widowpenalty4000%
  \sfcode`\.\@m}
 {\def\@noitemerr
   {\@latex@warning{Empty `thebibliography' environment}}%
  \endlist
```

Comment: From which `.cls` file exactly? The snippet you provided deals with the `thebibliography` environment and we would need the settings for the ToC.

Comment: The easiest solution is to add \raggedright or \sloppy into the chaper title (short version).